# Android app with QT and database

Tags: android, sql, qt, sqlite

Is there any way to make QT app that works with earlier created database?
I've created database using sqlite3 and now I'd like to work with this database in my android app. I came across some answers but sadly they didn't work.

Comment: Sure, have a look at `QSqlDatabase` and use the `QSQLITE` driver.

Comment: Would you mind telling me little bit more? I found some examples where people use QSqlDatabase but never in android. Where should I put my datbasefile.db that I would be able to connet to it via QSqlDatabase or how can i create new database, that would be loaded (instead of created) every time I launch my app in phone>